# Is every topological space homeomorphic to a subspace of a locally contractible space?

Tags: gn.general-topology

Is every topological space homeomorphic to a subspace of a locally contractible space?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_(topology)

Comment: @MikaeldelaSalle The cone on a Hawaiian earring is contractible (since it is a cone), but not locally contractible or even locally simply connected.

Comment: @BVQr: There are different notions of ``locally'' around. Sometimes it means that every point has a neighbourhood with that property, sometimes that there exists a neighbourhood base.

Comment: @BVQr My bad, I had interpreted your question in the other way.

Comment: @Zero the definition I use is a space $X$ is locally contractible at a point $x$ if for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ there is a neighborhood $V$ of $x$ contained in $U$ such that the inclusion of $V$ is nulhomotopic in $U$. A space is locally contractible if it is locally contractible at every point.

Comment: The answer is positive at least for nice spaces: every completely regular space embeds into $[0,1]^\kappa$ for some $\kappa$

Comment: Yes. A construction is due to R. Brown. For some details see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3897881/hausdorff-topological-group-is-topologically-isomorphic-to-a-subgroup-closed-of/3900648#3900648).